# multiple Evals in one page

Tags: c#

I have a repeater in C#, which generates unique li tags with IDs and have some other elements.

```
<li id="<%# Eval("myID") %>">
  <a id="<%# Eval("myID") %>"></a>
</li>
```

I get a markup error in VS, that 'Another object already exists with ID <%# Eval("myID") %>'

Why I can't use <%# Eval("myID") %> multiple times in the page? It compiles and runs, just it's marked as a warning..

it's C# 4.0, asp.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you want to give the `li` and the `a` the same ID?

You can use `Eval` as many times as you'd like.  You're using that value as the ID for two elements, though, and that's what VS is complaining about.

I might suggest

```
   <li id="li_<%# Eval("myID") %>">
     <a id="a_<%# Eval("myID") %>"></a>
   </li>
```

Answer (score 2):

For the simple reason that HTML id attributes should be unique on a page. If you need something to have association with some text, you should use another attribute, or mark them differently. Such as:

```
rel="<%# Eval("myId") %>"
class="<%# Eval("myId") %>"
```